# how to append custom text to generate d.ts file by typescript compiler?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to create a javascript module by TypeScript which is compatible with ES5 browsers and NodeJs modules. So I don't want to use the import and export in TypeScrtipt because it makes the output depends on SystemJS or RequireJS or commonJs. I have just created a library with namespace and add the following code to make it compatible with SystemJs:

```
// global html object (pure javascript compatiblity)
if (typeof window !="undefined") (<any>window).myNamespace = myNamespace;

// create exports
declare var module:any;
if (typeof module !="undefined") module.exports = {myNamespace};
```

Everything is OK, I just need to add the following code so I can use the library in NodeJS modules and have propery typing information

```
export {myNamespace}
```

So I can use my library in NodeJs lib like this:

```
import {myNamespace} from "../lib/myNamespace.js";
```

But I couldn't find how to tell the TypeScript compiler to add that export without creating a module in its own way. How can I add a few lines directly at the end of generated d.ts automatically after each compile such as:

```
Generated typing ..
...
...

// Custom declaration
// Remark Remark
export {myNamespace}
// Remark Remark
```

**Note: ** The modulation is none and many things are custom, I cannot use the regular export feature of typescript modulation.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I add a few lines directly at the end of generated d.ts

There is no TypeScript option to magically have some code only appear in the generate `.d.ts` if it doesn't exist in the origin `.ts`.

## Options

Add a build pipeline e.g. `gulp` / `grunt` and use their completion event to tag on more stuff after the `.d.ts` is generated.

Personally I would recommend reconsider why you need to do this.